# Align progress values in ganttchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, gantt

For the given gantt chart

```
\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid, vgrid, x unit=0.7cm, progress=today, today=4, newline shortcut=true, bar progress label node/.append style={right=5pt}]{1}{16}
\gantttitlelist[title list options={var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x using {"Year \y"}}]{1, 2, 3, 4}{4} \\
\gantttitlelist[title list options={var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x using {"Q\y"}}]{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}{1} \\
\ganttgroup[progress=25]{Progress}{1}{16} \\
\ganttbar{WP 1}{1}{1} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{WP 2}{2}{6} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{WP 3}{7}{16} 
\end{ganttchart}
```

[image]

is it possible to align the progress values to the right side (just as it is for WP 3 or the overall progress?

Answer (score 1):

See the default shifts on the manual page 30, for groups there is the values:

```
/pgfgantt/group left shift =-.1
/pgfgantt/group right shift =.1
```

If you set these values to 0 you will get the desired result.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}[
        %Gantchart config
        hgrid,
        vgrid,
        x unit=0.7cm,
        progress=today,
        today=4,
        newline shortcut=true,
        group right shift=0, % Line added
        group left shift=0, % Line added
        bar progress label node/.append style={right=5pt}
    ]{1}{16}
    \gantttitlelist[title list options={var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x using {"Year \y"}}]{1, 2, 3, 4}{4} \\
    \gantttitlelist[title list options={var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x using {"Q\y"}}]{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}{1} \\
    \ganttgroup[progress=25]{Progress}{1}{16} \\
    \ganttbar{WP 1}{1}{1} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{WP 2}{2}{6} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{WP 3}{7}{16} 
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unfortunately, I am looking for an alignment to the most left option (such as "Progress" or "WP 3").